# Set background image of app by a button click event

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

when a button is pressed  ,the background image of the app must may be changed to a image in the project .

i have tried to set the background image by modifying the visibility of  a XAML image control whose source points to the image in the project .But the problem in this case is that the image hides some of the XAML controls on setting visibility = true . I tried setting "send to back " and opacity options ,but no use in them .

Please tell  , if there is a solution for this problem or assist me in using the correct image XAML property to achieve my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `VisualBrush` to set your image as the background of your root element (Grid in this case). In your code, on button press set the `BackgroundImage` property to your image path and if you have some type of change notification for this property the image will be changed.

```
    <Grid.Background>
        <VisualBrush TileMode="None" Opacity="{Binding BackgroundOpacity}">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Image Source="{Binding BackgroundImage}"></Image>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
```

Comment: I guess VisualBrush does not work in windows store apps . Missing Assembly references !

Comment: Use ImageBrush than... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imagebrush.aspx